# What am I doing wrong in this Oracle SQL Update query that's supposed run across partitions?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here's the query I'm trying to run(supplied by a colleague)

```
FOR partition IN 1..32 LOOP
    lQuery := 'UPDATE CORE.tbl PARTITION(tbl' || LPAD(partition, 2, '0') '|| ') SET p1 = NULL '
           || 'WHERE p1 IS NOT NULL';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lQuery;
END LOOP;
```

where `CORE` is the db and `tbl` is the name of the table. However, Sql developer throws a bunch of errors when I try to run the script.

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
FOR partition IN 1..32 LOOP
Error report:
Unknown Command

Error starting at line 2 in command:
lQuery := 'UPDATE CORE.user_login PARTITION(user_login' || LPAD(partition, 2, '0') '|| ') SET password_md5 = NULL '
Error report:
Unknown Command

Error starting at line 3 in command:
|| 'WHERE password_md5 IS NOT NULL'
Error report:
Unknown Command

Error starting at line 5 in command:
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lQuery
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LQUERY" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "LQUERY" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Error starting at line 6 in command:
END LOOP
Error report:
Unknown Command
```

I have never worked with anything more than simple scripts in SQL and can't seem to figure out why the query is breaking. Any help on solving the issue would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I think the fundamental problem is that you need to wrap that code in `BEGIN..END` for it to be a single valid command.

As pointed out in another answer, you also have a syntax error within the code.

```
DECLARE
  lQuery VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR partition IN 1..32 LOOP
    lQuery := 'UPDATE CORE.tbl PARTITION(tbl' || LPAD(partition, 2, '0') || ') SET p1 = NULL '
           || 'WHERE p1 IS NOT NULL';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lQuery;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I get `ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'LQUERY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:` .. How do I declare `lQuery` correctly?

Comment: Edited to include variable declaration

Comment: And for future questions along the same lines, maybe at least skim the first chapter of http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm

Answer (score 1):

You've misplaced the single quotes where you do `'|| '`. Try this instead:

```
FOR partition IN 1..32 LOOP
    lQuery := 'UPDATE CORE.tbl PARTITION(tbl' || LPAD(partition, 2, '0') || ') SET p1 = NULL '
           || 'WHERE p1 IS NOT NULL';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lQuery;
END LOOP;
```

If you pay close attention to the syntax highlighting, you'll be able to spot these kinds of errors.

Comment: Ahh, was writing this answer but you got it on time.

Comment: I modified my statement with your suggestion in addition to the `BEGIN` and `END` statements but I'm not sure how I can declare `lQuery`.. My full trace is here https://codeshare.io/eXO2s . What am I doing wrong?