# How do I declare a query in an oracle pl/sql statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm fairly new to Oracle but Ive been tasked to write this statement .

```
BEGIN
FOR partition IN 1..32 LOOP
    lQuery := 'UPDATE CORE.tbl PARTITION(tbl' || LPAD(partition, 2, '0') || ') SET p = NULL '
           || 'WHERE p IS NOT NULL';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lQuery;
END LOOP;
END;
```

However, I get the following error

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
BEGIN
FOR partition IN 1..32 LOOP
    lQuery := 'UPDATE CORE.user_login PARTITION(user_login' || LPAD(partition, 2, '0') || ') SET password_md5 = NULL '
           || 'WHERE password_md5 IS NOT NULL';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lQuery;
END LOOP;
END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'LQUERY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 23:
PLS-00201: identifier 'LQUERY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

when I try to run it. I understand that this might be because of not declaring `lQuery` but  googling online showed me examples of declaring variables of a certain type such as (integer, varchar.. etc.) but none of them showed how to declare a query as this statement expects.

Comment: Your `lQuery` is just a variable and should be treated like one. It requires being declared (as some string-like value, `VARCHAR2` for example).

Comment: Are you sure you need to loop through the partitions?  With a table named `USER_LOGIN` your system should be able to update the whole thing in one statement.  (Also, +1 for removing insecure M5 password hashes!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What am I doing wrong in this Oracle SQL Update query that's supposed run across partitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884160/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-this-oracle-sql-update-query-thats-supposed-run-across)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement may be simply declared as a varchar2. For example:

```
declare
  vsql varchar2(1000);
  n   integer;
begin
  vsql := 'select 1 from dual';
  execute immediate vsql into n;
  dbms_output.put_line(n);
end;
```